# Debug MapReduce code to find the cause of NULLPointerException error

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am trying to run a MapReduce code to calculate average satisfaction level per department. Below is the sample data. The file has headers and in order to remove the headers I placed these in another txt file and used it to check if the row values are not equal to headers.

**Sample Data**
satisfaction_level,last_evaluation,number_project,average_montly_hours,time_spend_company,Work_accident,left,promotion_last_5years,sales,salary

0.38,0.53,2,157,3,0,1,0,sales,low
0.8,0.86,5,262,6,0,1,0,sales,medium
0.11,0.88,7,272,4,0,1,0,sales,medium
0.72,0.87,5,223,5,0,1,0,sales,low
0.37,0.52,2,159,3,0,1,0,sales,low
0.41,0.5,2,153,3,0,1,0,sales,low
0.1,0.77,6,247,4,0,1,0,sales,low
0.92,0.85,5,259,5,0,1,0,sales,low
0.89,1,5,224,5,0,1,0,sales,low

Below is my mapper code.

```
public class SatisfactionLevelMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, FloatWritable>
{
     String header;
 @Override
 protected void setup(Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
/* Headers are placed in a separate header.txt file for which the location is specified in the driver */
{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("header.txt"));
    header = bufferedReader.readLine();

}
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text text, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String row = text.toString();
    String [] values = row.trim().split(","); //dataset is a CSV file with 10 columns

    float satisfaction = 0.0f;
    String dept = null;
    try
    {
        if(values.length == 9 && header != row)
        {
            satisfaction = Float.parseFloat(values[0]);         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    context.write(new Text(dept), new FloatWritable(satisfaction));
    }
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException Error as below.

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.<init>(Text.java:88)
    at com.df.hra.SatisfactionLevelMapper.map SatisfactionLevelMapper.java:62)
    at com.df.hra.SatisfactionLevelMapper.map(SatisfactionLevelMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Is there a way to figure out which part of my code has the issue?
I am new to Java and trying to figure out a way to debug MapReduce codes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link.

Comment: You define `String dept = null;` and later `context.write(new Text(dept), ...` where `dept` is `null` yet but `Text` constructor expects a string.

Comment: String dept should be = values[8], not null. Also, I see 10 columns, not 9. Also, use equals() or !equals() to compare strings, not == or !=.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `Text` value with `null`, as you're doing here (with `dept`). Consider using an empty String (`""`) instead.